# Why is my binary search so insanely slow compared to an iterative?

Tags: c++, performance, search, time, binary-search

I'm writing an autocomplete program that finds all possible matches to a letter or set of characters given a dictionary file and input file. I just finished a version that implements a binary search over an iterative search and thought I could boost the overall performance of the program.

Thing is, the binary search is almost **9 times slower** than an iterative search. What gives? I thought I was improving performance by using a binary search over iterative.

Run time(bin search to the left)[[Larger]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gg1mH.png):
[image: testing the time of each version]

Here is the important part of each version, full code can be built and run at [my github](https://github.com/Gmercer015/AutoComplete) with cmake.

Binary Search Function(called while looping through input given)

---

```
bool search(std::vector<std::string>& dict, std::string in,
        std::queue<std::string>& out)
{
    //tick makes sure the loop found at least one thing. if not then break the function
    bool tick = false;  
    bool running = true;
    while(running) {
        //for each element in the input vector
        //find all possible word matches and push onto the queue
        int first=0, last= dict.size() -1;
        while(first <= last)
        {
            tick = false;
            int middle = (first+last)/2;
            std::string sub = (dict.at(middle)).substr(0,in.length());
            int comp = in.compare(sub);
            //if comp returns 0(found word matching case)
            if(comp == 0) {
                tick = true;
                out.push(dict.at(middle));
                dict.erase(dict.begin() + middle);      
            }
            //if not, take top half
            else if (comp > 0)
                first = middle + 1;
            //else go with the lower half
            else
                last = middle - 1;
        }
        if(tick==false)
            running = false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Iterative Search(included in main loop):

---

```
for(int k = 0; k < input.size(); ++k) {
        int len = (input.at(k)).length();
        // truth false variable to end out while loop
        bool found = false;
        // create an iterator pointing to the first element of the dictionary
        vecIter i = dictionary.begin();
        // this while loop is not complete, a condition needs to be made
        while(!found && i != dictionary.end()) {
            // take a substring the dictionary word(the length is dependent on
            // the input value) and compare
            if( (*i).substr(0,len) == input.at(k) ) {
                // so a word is found! push onto the queue
                matchingCase.push(*i);
            }
            // move iterator to next element of data
            ++i;    
        }

    }
```

---

example input file:

```
z
be
int
nor
tes
terr
on
```

Comment: By `a letter or set of letters` do you mean that they are at the beginning of the words searched?

Comment: @SJuan76 I edited in a sample files including search terms which were used in the picture and yes the letters are the beginning of the words.

Comment: `erase`ing an item within a `vector` is expensive.

Comment: Instead of using `substr` try using [`std::strncmp`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strncmp)

Comment: Do they give the exact same results?  Have you counted how many operations you do in each loop and compared them?

Comment: @MM. and also it is a thing that he does in the binary search version but not in the iterative one.

Comment: Why is your dictionary lookup removing elements from the dictionary anyway? Do you cross out words in your dictionary when you look them up, too? Also, `.at()` isn't fast either, doing a range check every time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of erasing elements in the middle of the vector (which is quite expensive), and then starting your search over, just compare the elements before and after the found item (because they should all be adjacent to eachother) until you find the all the items which match.

Or use [`std::equal_range`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/equal_range), which does exactly that.

Answer (score 2):

This will be the culprit:

```
dict.erase(dict.begin() + middle);
```

You are repeatedly removing items from your dictionary to naively use binary search to find all valid prefixes.  This adds huge complexity, and is unnecessary.

Instead, once you have found a match, step backwards until you find the first match, then step forwards, adding all matches to your queue.  Remember that because your dictionary is sorted and you are using only the prefixes, all valid matches will appear consecutively.

Answer (score 1):

dict.erase operation is linear in the size of dict: it copies the entire array from middle to end into the beginning of the array. This makes the "binary search" algorithm possible quadratic in the length of dict, with O(N^2) expensive memory copy operations.